# Add grid in listview

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store

I am looking for something like:

```
  lv.Children.Add(e1);
```

But lv.children.add does not exist

```
    <ListView x:Name="lv" Height="300" Margin="727,97,208,231" Grid.Row="1" >

        <Grid Name="e1" Height="48" Width="417" >
            <Image  Width="32" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5" Source="ms-appx:///img/coffee.png" />
            <TextBlock  Text="caffee" FontSize="18" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="40,0,26,5" ></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="$2" FontSize="18" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="5,5,30,5"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="caffee" FontSize="18" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="5,5,90,5"></TextBlock>
        </Grid>

    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use

```
  lv.Items.Add(e1);
```